# What's the purpose of dropdown-toggle class in bootstrap dropdowns?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown

Dropdown menus work perfectly with or without the `dropdown-toggle` bootstrap class being applied to `<button>` element,so why use it in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `dropdown-toggle` class adds the `outline: 0;` on `:focus` to the button, so when you click on the button it will not have the surrounding blue border of the "active" element.

Check the next two bottons:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .divider class is used to separate links inside the dropdown menu with a thin horizontal line:</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials - no border
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .divider class is used to separate links inside the dropdown menu with a thin horizontal line:</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials - with border
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tested and they both have the border, maybe it has another use.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but Firefox displays the dotted line anyway, that's why i got confused.

Comment: I just checked in firefox and there is no outline in any of them. It's probably a chrome-fix (and I guess safari/opera as well).

Comment: you are right,i think i need some sleep lol :) , FF doesn't display the outlines anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

It adds the following CSS properties, but they impact when dropdown button's content is displayed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's basically some `button` inner `box-shadow` when `.open`, as well as `color`, `background-color`, `border-color` and `outline` (on `:focus`) removal. Here a comparison between the two:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    With .dropdown-toggle <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Without .dropdown-toggle <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Difference tested in Chrome, Opera & Safari:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I get what you mean, but there's no visual difference what so ever! even the outline is still there, is it because i'm using firefox?

Comment: I tested also with IE, same, no visual difference.

Comment: Isn't this (almost) exactly the same as in my answer? you can voteup mince :) (cost no money, you know...)

Comment: I did vote you up, but he answered right first, so i gave him the 'Tick',thanks for help Dekel, Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @eghawk2k, my comment was for Syden :)

Comment: @Dekel, just upvoted yours, sure it is, but some properties were not mentioned but it is good as well.

Comment: Thanks @Syden, you got my vote for the extra details.

Answer (score 0):

```
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mailbox scale-up">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="drop-title">Pedidos preparados</div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div><p>hola</p></div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).