# BootStrap dropdown class unnecessary?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently messing around with Bootstrap trying to understand it. While reviewing Bootstrap's documentation on dropdowns, I came across the following code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
    id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
    expanded="false">
    Dropdown
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another 
            action</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else 
            here</button>
       </div>
</div>
```

which can be viewed [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/).

**I removed the outer `<div class="dropdown">` wrapper, and the code functioned perfectly fine** (view below).

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
expanded="false">
Dropdown
</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else 
        here</button>
    </div>
```

Apparently something similar happened with the `data-toggle` attribute - the code functions fine with or without it, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308134/whats-the-purpose-of-dropdown-toggle-class-in-bootstrap-dropdowns).

What I don't understand is, why does this still work? Why can we remove an outer `<div>` tag with essentially no repurcussion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, when you say it works fine, the drop down would show on toggle, but the position of the menu is not correct. This is because `.dropdown` has `position: relative;` which helps the `.dropdown-menu` to position correctly.

> `position: absolute;` require a parent element with `position:relative;`. In the below example it is the body tag, and it can be any
>   element depending on the structure.

**with .dropdown**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**without .dropdown** *(you can see the position of menu is bottom and not near the button)*

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```

**without .dropdown but with a relative parent**

```css
.another_parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="another_parent">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That appears to be true when I test it here on Stack. However, when I test on Chrome, the contents of the dropdown appear exactly as you would expect - close to the button as in your first example.

Comment: it depends how you have got the structure, as you know `position: absolute;` take the immediate parent with `position: relative;`. In SO, its the body tag, while in your case, it can be another tag. Its not necessary that you need `.dropdown`. Any parent element with `position: relative;` would do the job.

Comment: @Matthew i have edited the post, see the example 3. thanks

Comment: Got it. So ultimately it just has to do with positioning. The contents will still display, just not necessarily at the right spot.

Comment: exactly, any parent with `position:relative;` will help

Answer (score 1):

The only CSS for `.dropdown` is `position: relative`. It limits the scope of absolutely positioned child elements. In this case, the dropdown-menu that has `position: absolute` style.

Another thing worth noting is that when the dropdown-menu is open, the parent element receives `.show` class. If you remove this class, you are not able to close it anymore.

The div you removed works as a wrapper, but whenever you have a parent wrapper element, it should continue to work when you click the button.
It means it needs a parent element as a wrapper in order to work properly.